# Visual Basic Delete then inserting data

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview

this is the codes on delete button

```
 Dim res As Integer
        res = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)
        If res = vbYes Then

            If staffDB.SelectedRows.Count > -1 Then

                staffDB.Rows.RemoveAt(Me.staffDB.CurrentRow.Index)
                Me.Validate()
                Me.TblStaffLoginBindingSource.EndEdit()
                Me.TblStaffLoginTableAdapter.Update(Me.SampleDataSet)

                userArchive.DataGridView1.Rows.Insert(Me.staffDB.CurrentRow.Index)
                Me.Validate()
                userArchive.TblArchiveUserBindingSource.EndEdit()
                userArchive.TblArchiveUserTableAdapter.Update(userArchive.SampleDataSet)


            Else
                MessageBox.Show("You must select a row")
            End If
        End If
```

i have 2 forms. named userAccounts and userArchive. on the userAccounts form there is a  delete button and datagridview(named staffDB) which has data. Now when i click on a data on the datagridview and then click the delete button then it will delete the selected data but after that i want to now add the deleted data on the userArchive. the userarchive has a datagridview named Datagridview1 i wanted to insert the data that i deleted on useraccounts there.

Inshort I need to add the deleted data to archive. but i dont know how :(
id really appreciate some help.

if you need some more information about the question ill post pictures of my program.

Comment: what error you are getting ? or you are getting empty result in DGV1

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: userArchive.DataGridView1.Rows.Insert(Me.staffDB.CurrentRow.Index)

Answer (score 0):

You already removed the selected row. so when you are inserting in DGV1 you are getting the error.

Try this :

```
                TblArchiveUserTableAdapter.tables(0).rows.add(1) 'no_of_rows_selected) <--
                userArchiv.Datagridview1.dataSource=TblArchiveUserBindingSource.Tables(0)    <--
                userArchive.DataGridView1.Rows.Insert(Me.staffDB.CurrentRow.Index)  <--- this line reordered. 
                staffDB.Rows.RemoveAt(Me.staffDB.CurrentRow.Index)
                Me.Validate()
                Me.TblStaffLoginBindingSource.EndEdit()
                Me.TblStaffLoginTableAdapter.Update(Me.SampleDataSet)
                userArchive.TblArchiveUserBindingSource.EndEdit()
                userArchive.TblArchiveUserTableAdapter.Update(userArchive.SampleDataSet)
```

Comment: i edited somethings before i used your code then it shows Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound. after that i tried to put the code you gave me and it gives the same error. sorry for the confusion

Comment: That error is bit different then your Ques. and complicated one also. what is the name of your DataSource attached to DGV1 ?

Comment: im noob on vb so please tell me if something on what im gonna say is wrong. the DGV1 is on the userarchive form, the datasrouces are TblArchiveUserBindingSource and  TblArchiveUserTableAdapter?. im not sure if im stating the right answer.

Comment: it gives blue lines on this TblArchiveUserBindingSource.tables(0).rows.add(no_of_rows_selected) 
serArchive.Datagridview1.validate() it says 1. validate not member of system.windows.forms.datagridview1. 2.tabes not member of system.windows.forms.bindingsource. 3. no_of_rows is not declared.

Comment: TblArchiveUserTableAdapter has the blue lines . 1. tblarchiveusertableadapter is not declared. it may be inaccessible due to its protection level. i tried adding the form name on where the table adapter is which is userarchive.tblarachiveusertableadapter but then it gives the error tables is not a member of 'IVS.SampleDataSetTableAdapters.tblArchiveUserTableAdapter'